# net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND after creating an img element in JavaScript and trying to use it

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I created an `img` element in JavaScript and gave it a DataURI as a source:

```
img = new document.createElement('img');
img.src = saveFrame();
```

The saveFrame function returns a DataURI (which is valid), and when i try `console.log(img)` the image element seems alright, but when i try running `cctx.drawImage(img, x, y, cboard.width, cboard.height)` it throws the error.

What I've tried:

- using `var` : `var img = document.createElement('img')`
- using `new Image()` : `img = new Image()`

I expected the Image to get drawn onto the canvas (that's called cboard, and has a context: cctx)

Actual results:

- Firefox: gives no output in the console, and it doesn't work.
- Chromium: the code doesn't work and throws:
  [image]

Other info:

OS: Manjaro Linux | Chromium version: 110.0.5481.177 | Firefox version: 110.0

Comment: what does save frame do? From the error message it seems like you are not creating any valid data uri. In addition, you need to wait for the image to load after you assign the src, otherwise when you draw nothing will be there. Maybe create a jsfiddle or codepen to reproduce and share.

Comment: @RobLouie I have a canvas with the id "board", saveFrame() just takes a type and does `return board.toDataURL(type||'png');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fixed by using onload handler:**

```js
const board = document.getElementById('board');
const ctx = board.getContext('2d');

const board2 = document.getElementById('board2');
const ctx2 = board2.getContext('2d');

function draw(){
  ctx.moveTo(40,40);
  ctx.lineTo(40,80);
  ctx.lineTo(80,0);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function transfer(){
  img = new Image();
  img.src = board.toDataURL('png'); //saveFrame()

  img.onload = ()=>{
    ctx2.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  background: black;
}

canvas{
  background: white;
}

button{
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="board"></canvas>

<canvas id="board2"></canvas>

<button onclick="draw()">draw image</button>
<button onclick="transfer()">transfer image</button>
```

**using the `getImageData()` method is better, and doesn't require the onload handler:**

```js
const board = document.getElementById('board');
const ctx = board.getContext('2d');

const board2 = document.getElementById('board2');
const ctx2 = board2.getContext('2d');

function draw(){
  ctx.moveTo(40,40);
  ctx.lineTo(40,80);
  ctx.lineTo(80,0);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function transfer(){
  img = ctx.getImageData(0,0,board.width,board.height); //saveData()

  ctx2.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
body{
  background: black;
}

canvas{
  background: white;
}

button{
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="board"></canvas>

<canvas id="board2"></canvas>

<button onclick="draw()">draw image</button>
<button onclick="transfer()">transfer image</button>
```